# PPA: 'ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6' FORBIDDEN 403

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, curl

I have php 5.6 and apache2 Installed on the production server.

I get the error for my poject on my production server: `Call to undefined function curl_init()`

I have to install php-curl for my Project. I run `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`:

```
....
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
php5-mysql php5-common php5-curl
....

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ trusty/main php5-mysql amd64 5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
403  Forbidden
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ trusty/main php5-common amd64 5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
403  Forbidden
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ trusty/main php5-curl amd64 5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-mysql_5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-common_5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-curl_5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

running `apt-get update` displays the same for this ppa:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
403  Forbidden
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
403  Forbidden
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
403  Forbidden
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
403  Forbidden
```

What is the solution to install the php-curl? One of the ideas is to change the ppa but I am unable to find another one for php 5.6.

I have searched about 3 days on the internet and found a lot of similar problems, but I was unable to fix mine. I've tried everything I have found

Running `sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl` run successfully, but I still get the error for my poject on my production server: `Call to undefined function curl_init()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6` removed the old ppa.

Also for me worked `sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6`